# Neo4j: Find nodes with property name that contains string (in the property name, not the property value)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to find all nodes with properties that have a certain string?
Eg here with "ID":

```
  match (n) where exists( n[".*"+"ID"]) return n
```

(this does not work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you just the keys.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ANY(x IN KEYS(n) WHERE x =~".*ID") RETURN n, KEYS(n) AS myKeys
```

This will give you just the values.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ANY(x IN KEYS(n) WHERE x =~".*ID") 
RETURN n, [x IN KEYS(n) WHERE x =~".*ID" | n[x]] AS myValues
```

If you have apoc, this will give you the keys and the values.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ANY(x IN KEYS(n) WHERE x =~".*ID") 
WITH n, [x IN KEYS(n) WHERE x =~".*ID" | x] AS myKeys
RETURN id(n) AS nodeId, apoc.map.submap(n, myKeys) as submap
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you! I am returning n {.*}. Do you know if there's a way to return just the value of the x properties?  looks like n.x doesn't recognize x as the property.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful! I edited my answer to give you a few different options.